# How to simply get a machine code of exactly one assembly instruction?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly

How to simply  get a code of exactly one assembly instruction?

For example for "mov eax 0x14".
I want to get it in linux terminal preferably with gcc or gdm.

Comment: Did you mean "gdb" rather than "gdm"? Also, you didn't specify the language. Do you want inline asm in C or what?

Comment: I meant gdb of course.
I want convert from, say intel notation to machine code, for example:
"nop" -> "0x90"
I can do it with examining memory in gdb, but it isn't the simplest method I expect.
Output can be a sequence of (one or more) hexadecimal numbers or something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ echo "mov eax, 0x14" | as -o /dev/null -al -msyntax=intel -mnaked-reg
GAS LISTING             page 1


   1 0000 B8140000  mov eax,0x14
   1      00
```

Comment: thank you, I'm working under bad OS now ;)  but I'll check it a few hours later

Comment: (gdb) disas /r main works quite well for my applications, but I tried this in gdb from mingw and "disas /r" didn't work - interesting - why?
Under linux I haven't this problem.

Answer (score 2):

rasm2 from the radare2 package fits this purpose nicely:

```
$ rasm2 'nop'
90
$ rasm2 -d '90'
nop
```

http://radare.org/y/?p=examples&f=rasm